# How to place textview on the layout border in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create an layout as shown in the figure.
 [image: img]

In that image shipped to is attached to the border of the layout. how to overlap like that.

Here is the XML I am using to create that

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/shipped_to_header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/address_blue_border" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_shipped_to"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/homebackground"
                android:text="Shipped To"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_door_no"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_shipped_to"
                android:text="22"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_address_line1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_door_no"
                android:text="Delhi, India"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_address_line2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_address_line1"
                android:text="Swindon Senegal BS32 8FE"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think you can achieve that using `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Paste the code (the XML mainly).

Comment: I have edited my question with XML. Please check that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_door_no"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="22" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_address_line1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Delhi" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_address_line2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some more dara" />
        </LinearLayout>

          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_shipped_to"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Ship To"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
             />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your image is a bit toooo small. Anyway, for that, use RelativeLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="#ccff00"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <!-- Your other TextViews -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#ccffff"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I used but I can't able to get it like that

Comment: updated my answer. you can make something like that. For the border, you create a separate drawable for that. Using Shapes with <stroke> and <corner> tags.

Comment: Ok. let me try that. Thanks.

Comment: PS: place that inside a Relative Layout and you may also replace the Linear Layout with any layout you want then put your contents there.. :)

--Already updated it with the relative layout container

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <!--  This is the main content -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" android:background="@drawable/frame"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="20dp">

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Main Content" android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--  This is the title label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white" android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Testing"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can have your answer at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155353/legend-and-fieldset-in-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714873/android-layout-like-legend-and-fieldset)

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a layout similar to the one it's in the image you have to use command `android:layout_margin` with negative values.

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```